# detect at compile time whether exceptions are disabled

Tags: c++, exception

I'm trying to detect at compile time whether exceptions have been disabled with the (`-fno-exceptions`) switch. I've tried to evaluate:

`noexcept(throw)`

But this won't compile if the exceptions are disabled under both gcc and clang.

EDIT: Take a look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/feature_test).

Comment: How about setting `-DNO_EXCEPTIONS` at the same place you're setting `-fno-exceptions`, and checking for `#ifdef NO_EXCEPTIONS`? --- Since disabling exception support is non-conforming, implementation-defined behaviour, I doubt there is a "standard" way to detect the disabled support. Then again, you *never* know with C++. ;-)

Comment: There is, I just found it: the macro [__cpp_exceptions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_exceptions.html)

Comment: ...which is not defined by the standard, but the implementation (GCC). q.e.d. ;-)

Comment: Yes, but it supposedly recommended, at least, by the WG21.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The symbol `__cpp_exceptions` is set by gcc when you have exceptions enabled. Then add a macro that either expands to nothing or your exception handling. There are examples for that in the documentation here:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_exceptions.html

At least clang is compatible with gcc in this sense - you may need a different variant in a Microsoft (or MS compatible) compiler. I'm assuming gcc and/or clang based on the name of the option.

Answer (score 9):

As always, it's fairly easy to check which macros are pre-defined for a particular compiler with a given set of command line parameters:

```
$ g++ -dM -E -x c++ - < /dev/null &> except.txt
$ g++ -dM -E -x c++ -fno-exceptions - < /dev/null &> no-except.txt
$ sdiff -s except.txt no-except.txt 
#define __EXCEPTIONS 1                            <
#define __cpp_exceptions 199711                   <
$
```

Comment: I like the DIY approach.

Answer (score 2):

In case of gcc you can check the following macro:

> __EXCEPTIONS
>
> This macro is defined, with value 1, when compiling a C++ source file with exceptions enabled. If -fno-exceptions is used
>   when compiling the file, then this macro is not defined.